# Is it possible to add google adsense to Bitbucket pages

Tags: html, static, bitbucket, adsense

I'm planning to put my blog projects, works and example to bitbucket pages. I was wondering if its possible to put Adsense to each of my bitbucket pages? will it work?

Answer (score 1):

It should work, yes. Those pages are served statically, so you should be able to embed the ad code on your pages.